# Robust Rails CMS

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, content-management-system, activeadmin

Im doing development in Rails that requires a good bit of friendly hand off to the client. For a bit, I have used Active Admin and out of the box it seems to work for the use cases I have run into like CRUD actions on model resources. However, a new app I am building involves the the ability for the client to essentially edit everything on the website and add new pages. It seems that I could get Active Admin to do this but it would take an incredibly long time. So, here are my thoughts: Try and extend Active Admin and see where that goes, build a CMS from scratch and wrap it around an Admin namespace or something similar, or see if there is a more robust CMS (does not have to be free), that comes with rich features, i.e. templating, new page creation, wyswig editor, rich text editor, etc. Think more Wordpress style CMS. What are your guys thoughts? Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend [this CMS](https://github.com/comfy/comfortable-mexican-sofa), worked with it for some years now.

Comment: avoid link only answers please